# tengo un problema de error ( Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\SUECAM\includes\sql.php on line 197)

Tags: php, array

```
elseif($login_level['group_status'] === '0'):
      $session->msg('d','Este nivel de usaurio esta inactivo!');
redirect('home.php',false);
```

este es el codigo el cual me da error: podria alguien ayudarme por favor.

(la linea 97 es justamente la del elseif debajo de esta)

Comment: El mensaje del título dice **197** ¿y estás colocando la 97?

Comment: adicional el error indica que estas accesando a un indice en una variable que es de tipo bool; eso quiere decir que tu consulta o dato son incorrectos...

Comment: //cod para saber si el estado del grupo está desactivado
     elseif($login_level['group_status'] === '0'):
           $session->msg('d','Este nivel de usaurio esta inactivo!');
           redirect('home.php',false);      es la linea 197 la del elseif.

Comment: ¿Qué muestra un `var_dump($login_level);`? Es cuestión de **depurar** tu código.

Comment: como puedo hacer un var_dum? como seria el codigo?